# Open, minimise or maximise Google Chrome developer tools by clicking on an icon?

Tags: google-chrome

**Is there a way to open Chrome developer tools by clicking on an icon?**

Does Chrome offer icons which I could place on toolbars?
Is it possible to open devtools from an extension? (Direct call, create custom keyboard event, else?)
Place it in a bookmark on bookmarks bar?

Comment: Why click when you can press? ctrl+shift+I

Comment: I personally, love the shortcut (⌥⌘I), but my colleague feels more comfortable clicking, so I was wondering if it's possible...

Comment: F12 works as well?

Comment: @Martin So you're on OS X? Or is your question about Chrome in general?

Comment: I'm on OS X, my colleague on Ubuntu... but my question is about Chrome in general... That's why I didn't mention any OS in the question itself.

Comment: @slhck Would your answer differ if I said *OS X only*? (if you have one)

Comment: <kbd>F12</kbd> should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Chrome offer icons which I could place on toolbars

Chrome does, but for this you'll have to create a custom Chrome Entension and even after creating, it can only bring up the extension's option page defined in the manifest

> Place it in a bookmark on bookmarks bar

THeroretically yes. The URL to developer tools is `chrome://chromewebdata`. Practically, this doesn't work and the developer tools pops up on clicking this URL **only if** an instance of developer tools is already open

Answer (score 0):

This URL opens Chrome Devtools however it opens it in full screen (covering the entire browser area):

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.html
```

There are query params to this URL like this:

```
dockSide=bottom&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)
```

In this, I am guessing if I can find alternate values for query parameter `dockSide`, we can control the size/location of the developer tools dock and place it according to our wish.

I tried playing with other query params `toolbarColor` and `textColor` with no luck though :(

Any suggestions would be a great help!!